# Hangfire history graph shows only last hour of data

Tags: hangfire

I have set recurring job which runs every minute. Realtime graph shows small bumps every minute and task does run. History graph shows only last hour (with incorrect count most of the time), e.g. there is no really history.

I am using PostgreSQL storage.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: If I use 2 recurring jobs I get empty history graph.